# How to deal with oversampling and undersampling of countries to be able to compare them?

Tags: independence, percentage, oversampling, under-sampling

I have a dataset that looks like this:

| cc | samples | population | % sample |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| US | 100 | 1,000 | 1% |
| CA | 20 | 100 | 20% |
| BR | 9 | 10 | 90% |
| AU | 600 | 300 | 200% |

I have **samples** from a certain **population** and the **percentage** of samples taken over a period of 6 months.

I categorize **samples** based on two characteristics (**A** and **B**). After, I calculated the percentage of samples that have characteristic **A**  and **B** based on the number of samples. For instance, for US I get that 20% of the samples have A characteristic and 80% have B, for CA 50% samples have A and 50% B, for BR 100% have A, and for AU I get 80% A and 20% B.

I want to compare countries and determine which countries have more presence of characteristic A. I don't know how to deal with the fact that some countries are oversampled and others are undersampled. In this example, BR will be the country on top, followed by AU, then CA a d US.

Can I really compare countries? If yes, what will be the best way? Or could I just describe that the observation based on the number of samples, and show the population in the table, so it is clear that there is oversample and undersample?

Any help is welcome, maybe the answer is simple, but I can't see it yet.

Comment: How come you ended up having sampled twice the AU population? It seems you haven't explained whether the sampling is with or without replacement.

Comment: I got this data, so I did not do the sample, but it was sampled with replacement, so some samples might be repeated.

Comment: You probably need to remove units that were multiply sample, taking only one random sample of those sampled with replacement.  Other than that you don't need to take the sampling fractions into account as long as the sampling used probability samples with all members of the populations having equal chance of being surveyed.